# Get current bluetooth discoverability timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making an app that requires the user's bluetooth discoverability/visibility timeout to "Never time out".

I use the following code to ask the user to change the current settings.

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);           
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

However, I don't want to bother the user if bluetooth discoverability is already on.

Is there a way to get the device's current discoverability timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the following:

```
BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (ba.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE)
{
    //Launch the intent to set timeout
}
```

You should also make sure that the Adapter is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

There is [hidden `getDiscoverableTimeout`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java#1519) function on `BluetoothAdapter` which returns number of seconds as timeout. You can access it by reflection:

```java
try {
    java.lang.reflect.Method method;
    method = bluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("getDiscoverableTimeout");
    int value = (int) method.invoke(bluetoothAdapter);
    // ... use the value
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // ... error handling
}
```

Be aware that this is hidden function so it may be forbidden or removed one day.